# RAM Dual Channel Confusion.

Tags: memory, ddr3, ddr

I got 4 slots of memory fitted with 4 memory sticks.

Originally, I had 2 corsair xms3 4gb 2x2gb memory stick kit but 1 of the 4 sticks broke due to circumstances, which leaves me with 1 kit and a half.

Anyway slots 1 to 3 are fitted with the the corsair sticks and on the 4th slot, I fitted a stick of another brand but with the same size and frequency. All 4 of the sticks run at 1333mhz.

The manual for my mobo, which is a gigabyte 880 ga ud3h rev 2.2, the 4 slots are divided to 2 channels, slots 1-2 for channel 0 and slot 3-4 for channel 1.

And here's how I installed my memory sticks.

Slot 1: Corsair Xms3
Slot 2: Corsair Xms3
Slot 3: Corsair Xms3 
Slot 4: Crucial 2gb

Remember that I originally had 2 corsair kits but one of the sticks broke, which left me with 3 corsair sticks which is effectively 1 kit and a half, while I took a crucial 2gb stick to replace the broken corsair stick.

Now my expectation are these, that slot 1-2 (channel 0) will run at dual channel while slots 3-4 (channel 1) will run at single channel since they don't have the same brand.

But the cpu-z report I got is different,

[image]

As you can see, slots 2-4 (which includes the crucial 2gb stick) are running in dual and slot 1 (despite being a corsair stick) is running in single.

Now this poses 3 question in my mind.

1. How is it that out of all the 4? the corsair stick gets singled out instead of the crucial stick?
2. Why are there 3 sticks running in dual mode if dual mode means 2 sticks working together as one? shouldn't it be only 2 sticks for slot 1 and 2? the rest should be running in single mode.

Comment: The problem is that you are looking at the `ranks` property of each memory module, and assuming that this information is the same as the single/dual channel operation of the modules.  It's not.  
The ranks information has nothing to do with single or dual channel operation.  You haven't provided any information on how those memory modules are operating.  Your assumptions on what mode your modules are operating in is simply wrong since they are based on the wrong information.

Comment: Try using the `Memory` tab instead of the `SPD` tab to get the number of memory channels in use.